# algorithm to generate relative precedence number

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, probability

I want to write a module/function, which takes input an unsigned integer(32-bit) and outputs 8-bit value. **output values must be in relative order as input.**
and the **output value once assigned should not be altered**.

testing:

input: randomly generated 32-bit integer

output: in range 0-255

repeat the action 256 times.. till the output values are exhausted.

**all output values should be relatively in same order as input values.**

**EDIT:** Based on comments, it is impossible to find a perfect solution for this.
However, Can we find best solution possible. i.e without comparing the input(32-bit) values.. generating relative order output of size 8-bit.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with (x>>24) i.e. just return top 8 bits?

Comment: top 8-bits might be same in all 256 inputs... in that case all output values will be same.

Comment: mask them with time and than store it in static varible

Comment: inputs will be taken one at a time..and output should be generated at the same time.. 
output value once generated, must not be used again.
@BhargavModi I did not understand how your solution works.
can you please elaborate a little.

Comment: @Rakesh top 8 bits should get masked by using AND operation with time in second and now the output should get saved in a variable for further use

Answer (score 1):

Assume the first input number is 123456. You don't know whether the following numbers will be smaller or greater than this. So the best thing to do is to output a number in the middle of the available range: 127.

Store this assignment (123456,127).

Now, if the second number is greater, e.g. 234567, output a number form the upper half of the output range:
(234567,191)

With each following number, output the center of the corresponding output range:
(200000, 159)

You get the idea.

Of course, depending on the input sequence, you normally cannot assign unique output to each input.

Worst case:
Input sequence 2^31, 2^30, ... i.e. 2147483648, 1073741824 yields output 127, 63, 31, 15, 7, 3, 1, 0, 0, ...
So you can only use 8 of the 256 available output numbers.

You can however fine tune this near the limits of the input range. If the input number is smaller than 127, then output == input.

Comment: Thankyou for your solution.

I am already using the same algorithm..
but it is broken by **just** 10 input values. i.e., inputs 10 to 1 in decrementing order.
can we improve this by utilizing the gap that is left while assigning output values..

for example.. if first input is 10 output is 127 
second input is 9 output will be 64.

values between 64-127 are not used..
can we improve our algo to use the gap also.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment objecting to the idea of simply taking the top bits, and reading between the lines of "till the output values are exhausted", it *sounds* like you want an algorithm which:

- Takes 256 distinct 32-bit integers as its input
- Returns the values `0..255` associated with those integers, in order.

But of course this is simply a **sort** algorithm. Sort the 256 inputs, and then the output value is the 0-based index in the sort result.

If you're looking for some way to return the output value without having first examined all the inputs, it's pretty clear that that's not possible, given your "output value once assigned should not be altered" requirement.

Comment: I understand that it is impossible to sort, until all the inputs are examined.

Can you suggest an algorithm to minimize the collision.
for example: an algorithm which gives unique and relative output till 50 or 100 or 150 input values in my case..

Comment: [Henrik's answer does just that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28605544), although I suspect you will never be able to *guarantee* a minimum number of values that can be accommodated - whatever system you use, there will always be a possible sequence of inputs to 'break' it

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sorting problem in disguise.

You can't output anything until you've seen all the values - unless you're under-specifying the problem, and there's a limit on the number of inputs.

If you have the intuitive limit of 256 inputs, whatever output you assign the first input, you can come up with less than 255 inputs such that you won't be able to map them.